# Using QueueChannel in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am working on the below case study.

1. Create a Rest Service to accept Reference id.
2. Use the Reference Id to get data (CLOB) from Database.
3. Put the data(CLOB) in a channel(queue) for further processing.
4. Reply to the rest client with response data in JSON format {"status": true,"message": "RECEIVED"}

I have the Rest Service created and using the Ref Id am getting the data from database but I am unable to send the response back to the rest client after putting the message in a channel(queue).
The  output received by Rest Client is : **No reply received within timeout**

Basically I want the request thread to be returned immediately after the data (CLOB) is pushed to the channel(queue).

Below is the configuration.

```
<int:channel id="responseChannel"/>
<int:channel id="initCalculation">
   <int:queue/>
</int:channel>


<!-- GET -->
<int-http:inbound-gateway 
    request-channel="httpGetChannel"
    reply-channel="responseChannel"
    supported-methods="GET"
    path="/init/{refId}"
    payload-expression="#pathVariables.refId">

    <int-http:request-mapping  produces="application/json"/>

</int-http:inbound-gateway>


<int:chain input-channel="httpGetChannel" output-channel="initCalculation">
    <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
            id="outbound-gateway-storedproc-get-forma" data-source="dataSource"
            is-function="false"
            stored-procedure-name="XX_EMPROC.GET_FRMA"
            ignore-column-meta-data="true"
            expect-single-result="true">

        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="V_REF_ID" direction="IN" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="V_FRMA"   direction="OUT" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CLOB}"/>

        <int-jdbc:parameter name="V_REF_ID" expression="payload" />
    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

    <!- Convert to JSON Format -->
    <int:service-activator ref="brInitGateway" method="getResponse"/>

</int:chain>


<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="initCalculation"  ref="brInitGateway"   method="process"/>
```

Kindly advise on the corrections needed in the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, there is no body who sends message as a reply to the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>`. You have declared `responseChannel`, but who is going to use it as an `output-channel`?

I'd suggest you to do this:

```
<publish-subscribe-channel id="responseChannel"/>

<int:chain input-channel="httpGetChannel" output-channel="responseChannel">


 <int:bridge input-channel="responseChannel" output-channel="initCalculation"/>
```

So, what happens here:

The `publish-subscribe-channel` for the `reply-channel` makes an internal bridge to the `replyChannel` header as one of the subscribers.

You send a result from the `<chain>` to that channel. Therefore the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` gets its reply.

Having that `<int:bridge>` from response to the `initCalculation` you have a second subscriber and, therefore, send a message to the required queue.

If you are not interested in the `brInitGateway.getResponse()` as a reply for the HTTP request, you should consider do not have that `reply-channel="responseChannel"` at all, but still use some `<publish-subscribe-channel>` to send to the queue and some transformer to prepare a reply, e.g.:

```
<transformer input-channel="prepareProcess" expression="' {"status": true,"message": "RECEIVED"}'"/>
```

This transformer is without `output-channel` because it is going to send its result into the `replyChannel` header, therefore to the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` initiator.

Comment: You can also use an inbound channel adapter instead of a gateway if you don't send a reply; it will send a 200OK by default, when you hand off the CLOB to the queue channel.

Comment: @GaryRussell - Thanks for the suggestion. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Artem Bilan - Thanks for your solution. It worked perfectly for my use case.